# bookmarklet to overlay css layer?

Tags: javascript, css, bookmarklet

I've been searching for how to write a bookmarklet which overlays the full screen with a layer filled with a color. Ie. Click the bookmarklet and a layer sits on top of the content.

The other trick I.am trying to solve is to.have a 'hole' aka a transparent part of the layer, eg 200px square in the middle of the overlay layer where you can see through to the original web page content underneath.

Are there any css wizards out there who could help me? Much appreciated... I'm a bit of a css newbie.

Cheers and thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> I've been searching for how to write a bookmarklet which overlays the full screen with a layer filled with a color. Ie. Click the bookmarklet and a layer sits on top of the content.

How about this? The following works for me:

```
javascript:(function(a){a=document.createElement('div');a.style.position=
'fixed';a.style.left=a.style.right=a.style.top=a.style.bottom='0%';
a.style.zIndex='100000';a.style.background='white';a.innerHTML=
'overlay content goes here';document.body.appendChild(a);})();
```

I'm not sure about the hole though; sorry. You may have to create separate elements that form the shape, but that of course is an ugly solution.

Comment: I prefer bookmarklets to be reasonably small. Anyway, it's not minified to the point of obfuscation; it's still 'straight'.

Comment: someone can always minify it themselves... this is supposed to be a learning environment.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an example that only uses CSS**

http://jsfiddle.net/QZV4D/

you can modify the hole by adjusting the % of the left and right overlays

Comment: Thanks Samccone! Cool code! How would I turn this into a bookmarklet? Also, is there a way to have it as a hole, like a donut, your great example is almost perfect but it is more like strips visible-invisible-visible... is there a way to make it more like a transparent box/hole rather than a transparent strip... I hpe that makes sense... Thank you! So cool.